# NoReverseMatch when use get_absolute_url()

Tags: django, django-models

models:

```
class Band(models.Model):
B_Name = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)
Country = models.CharField(max_length=30)
genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre)
imageband = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/band')

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.B_Name

@models.permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('thu', (), {
        'B_Name': self.B_Name})
```

urls:

```
url(r'^genre/(\d+)/$', 'genre', name="genre"),  
url(r'^thu/(?P<B_Name>[-\w]+)/$', 'thu', name='thu'),
```

view:

```
def genre(request, url):
   template = 'genre/genre.html'
   if url=='1':
      tmp = Band.objects.raw('SELECT B_Name, Country FROM data_band WHERE genre_id=%s',    ...)
   if ....
   return render_to_response(template,{'tmp':tmp})


def thu(request):
      template = 'genre/thu.html'
      tmp = Band.objects.raw('SELECT B_Name, genre FROM data_band')
      return render_to_response(template,{'tmp':tmp})
```

If i use B_Name="AB", it's working, but i use B_Name="A B", it's error:

NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'thu' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'B_Name': u'A B'}' not found.

Comment: Why are you using `raw` queries rather than standard `filter` calls?

Comment: it's my habit, what's the different between filter and raw?

Comment: @skidrow: namely, `filter` makes use of the Django DBAPI which is database-agnostic, whereas `raw` directly queries the database, and thus, is inherently dependent of the particular database being used by your app at this moment in time. If you ever needed to switch to a different DB platform, any or all of your `raw` queries could break. Additionally, using `filter` (and the rest of the DBAPI) makes your code more readable and more maintainable. As a general rule, `raw` is only for "nothing else will do" scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url named `thu` does not allow spaces in the `B_Name` parameter. It should be

```
url(r'^thu/(?P<B_Name>[-\w ]+)/$', 'thu', name='thu'),
```

Note the space in `[-\w ]`.

It is common to create a [slug field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#slugfield) for your model that does not contain any spaces, and use that in your urls.

Answer (score 2):

Of course. Your urlpattern is:

```
url(r'^thu/(?P<B_Name>[-\w]+)/$', 'thu', name='thu'),
```

`[-\w]+` means "any *non-space* character or '-' one or more times". You've explicitly told it to not accept a space, so it doesn't.

Just substitute that regex with something like `[-\w ]+` (notice the space before the closing bracket) and it'll work. However, it's really not a good idea to include spaces in URLs.